# Is there a way to import compare_ssim for python IDLE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I tried running the python code in IDLE to import compare_ssim with this command line,

from skimage.measure import compare_ssim: [code for importing compare_ssim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJbdX.jpg)

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
from PIL import Image
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Flatten
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing import image
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
#from maskalgo import getMask
from DefectSniffer import sniff
import time
```

But I am having this error: [Error shown in idle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BB8w.jpg)

```
Python 3.7.8 (tags/v3.7.8:4b47a5b6ba, Jun 28 2020, 08:53:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
=============== RESTART: C:\Users\User\Desktop\keras\Training.py ===============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\keras\Training.py", line 13, in <module>
    from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
ImportError: cannot import name 'compare_ssim' from 'skimage.measure' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\__init__.py)
>>>
```

How do I resolve this issue? Please and thank you.

Comment: Please add your error traceback and code as Text. It is difficult for people to help you if you put images.

Comment: thx for feedback

Answer (score 4):

As per - https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/b38fd6f02917db2965f5faf2e6e18fc197b8d6c8/skimage/metrics/_structural_similarity.py#L17

versionchanged:: 0.16
This function was renamed from `skimage.measure.compare_ssim` to
`skimage.metrics.structural_similarity`

Answer (score 1):

skimage.measure library has been renamed now. Instead of

`from skimage.measure import compare_ssim`

use

`from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity`

Comment: Duplication of other answer.